# I can get the click button to show images, but not to take them away

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make some basic panels from bootstrap but body of the 2nd panel is shorter than the first, when I try to increase the height of panel 2 it won't let me, however it will let me decrease the height, so my question is, how do I increase the height of the body on panel 2.

```html
<div class="panel panel-primary" id="panel1" style="width: 15%";>
      <div class="panel-heading">Image Split</div>
      <div class="panel-body">An image split into difference sections with different links</div>
      <div class="panel-footer panel-primary" id="footer1">
          <button onclick="window.location.href='imagesplit.html'" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn">CLICK HERE</button>
      </div>
</div> 

<div class="panel panel-primary" id="panel2" style="width: 15%";>
      <div class="panel-heading">Boolean</div>
      <div class="panel-body" style="max-height: 100";>A simple addition example of boolean</div>
      <div class="panel-footer panel-primary" id="footer1">
          <button onclick="window.location.href='boolean.html'" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn">CLICK HERE</button>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not sure why it has done that to my code either, was fine in the preview.

Comment: I tried to do the same but was unsuccessful. I would like to see answers. Very good question !

Comment: doesn't help that I've massively messed up with this post

Comment: and btw I used 'margin-top' that worked for me, however, any text I enter starts half way down and I can't figure out how to get the text back to the top.